# Fade in/out to segment on page

Tags: html, css

Currently I have a website where the content is all on a single page.

The Menu items, when you click them, jump to the relevant part of the page.

But the jump effect is still jarring and doesn't give a sleek feeling. I think fading in and out would be a cooler effect.

Is it possible to make the Jump action simulate a FadeIn/FadeOut effect?

I just have simple Jump HTML code like this:

```
<a href="#Part1">Menu Item 1</a>

<a href="#Part2">Menu Item 2</a>
```

And the goal would be that for example if you click `Menu Item 2`, "Part1" content would fade out and then fade in "Part 2" content.

Thanks!

Comment: Try giving [`scroll-behavior: smooth`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/scroll-behavior)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Switch the `href` with a data attribute, in our case, `data-href`.

Using JavaScript, detect when the user clicks the link. When detected, fade out the document and set a timeout to fade back in in 500 milliseconds. After fading in, select the element defined in the `data-href` attribute and use `.scrollIntoView()`

```js
$('.fade-link').on('click', function() {
  $(document.body).fadeOut();
  var t = $(this);
  setTimeout(function() {
    $(document.body).fadeIn();
    $(t.data('href')).get(0).scrollIntoView();
  }, 500);
});
```

```css
.content {
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  border:1px solid;
}

#a {
  margin-top: 500px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a data-href="#a" href="#" class="fade-link">First</a>
<a data-href="#b" href="#" class="fade-link">Second</a>
<a data-href="#c" href="#" class="fade-link">Third</a>
<div class="content" id="a">
First
</div>
<div class="content" id="b">
Second
</div>
<div class="content" id="c">
Third
</div>
```

Vanilla JS solution:

```js
var links = document.getElementsByClassName("fade-link");
function handle(){
  document.body.style.opacity="0";
  var t = this;
  setTimeout(function(){
    document.body.style.opacity="1";
    document.querySelector(t.getAttribute("data-href")).scrollIntoView();
  }, 500);
}
for(let i = 0; i < links.length; i++){
  links[i].addEventListener("click", handle);
}
```

```css
body{
  transition:0.5s opacity;
}
.content {
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  border:1px solid;
}

#a {
  margin-top: 500px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a data-href="#a" href="#" class="fade-link">First</a>
<a data-href="#b" href="#" class="fade-link">Second</a>
<a data-href="#c" href="#" class="fade-link">Third</a>
<div class="content" id="a">
First
</div>
<div class="content" id="b">
Second
</div>
<div class="content" id="c">
Third
</div>
```

Comment: @user15763749 Glad to help :). If you want a vanilla JS solution, just let me know.

Answer (score 1):

#### This another approach from W3Schools here try it for best practice, also you can visite full tutorial: [w3schools tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_smooth_scroll.asp#section1)

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  // Add smooth scrolling to all links
  $("a").on('click', function(event) {

    // Make sure this.hash has a value before overriding default behavior
    if (this.hash !== "") {
      // Prevent default anchor click behavior
      event.preventDefault();

      // Store hash
      var hash = this.hash;

      // Using jQuery's animate() method to add smooth page scroll
      // The optional number (800) specifies the number of milliseconds it takes to scroll to the specified area
      
      $('body').fadeOut(100);
      
      setTimeout(function(){
        $('body').fadeIn(100);
        $('html, body').animate({
          scrollTop: $(hash).offset().top
        }, 0, function(){

          // Add hash (#) to URL when done scrolling (default click behavior)
          window.location.hash = hash;
        });
      },200)
    } // End if
  });
});
```

```css
#section1 {
  height: 600px;
  background-color: pink;
}

#section2 {
  height: 600px;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h1>Smooth Scroll</h1>

<div class="main" id="section1">
  <h2>Section 1</h2>
  <p>Click on the link to see the "smooth" scrolling effect.</p>
  <a href="#section2">Click Me to Smooth Scroll to Section 2 Below</a>
  <p>Note: Remove the scroll-behavior property to remove smooth scrolling.</p>
</div>

<div class="main" id="section2">
  <h2>Section 2</h2>
  <a href="#section1">Click Me to Smooth Scroll to Section 1 Above</a>
</div>
```

**Thanks**
*Sayed021*